# How to capture an output from a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, arguments

I have a simple function

```
function increase(percent, number)

    low = number - number*percent;

end
```

I want to return low so I can use it as an argument for another function

```
mitoGen(asp, arg, increase(0.2, 234), glu)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/function.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As such:

```
function low = increase(percent, number)
  low = number - number*percent;
end
```

You can also return multiple items by having more than one thing to the left of the equal sign:

```
function [out1, out2] = foo(bar, baz)
```