# This MATLAB function returns a vector of results

Tags: matlab, output-parameter

If I have a function in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), and within it I have a loop, that calculates two variables, something like:

```
for index = 1:1000,
    var1 = 0.0;
    var2 = zeros(size(someMatrix));
    ...
    %some calculus...
    ...
end
```

How do I define the function to return those two variables, but with all changes they suffered while in the loop, like

```
var1 = [1, 3, 5, 7]
var2 = some matrix,
```

So instead the function returns a single value. How do I return a vector of results, gotten from the loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture an output from a function in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908753/how-to-capture-an-output-from-a-function-in-matlab)

Comment: Matlab is the only language I know that can return more than one variable from a function. It is a really cool feature, and I wonder if any other language has this too.

Comment: @ja72: Python allow multiple return values. See [Multiple Return Values](http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/functions/) for an example. You may search for *multiple-returns.py*.

Comment: @Jonas, maybe it change because it returns like the history of the 2 vars inside a loop. not only their values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I knew what you were trying to do at a higher level I might be able to give you better advice.  When I read this question I ask myself "Why would he want to do that?".  Chances are there is a much better way to do what you are trying to do.

That being said, I think you are attempting to do something like this.

```
function [x y] = foo
x = 0;
y = 0;
for i = 1:100
  if x(end)<i
      x(end+1)=i^2;
  end
  if y(end)^3<x(end)
      y(end+1)=sqrt(x(end));
  end
end

>> [x y] = foo
x =
     0     1     4    25   676
y =
     0     1     2     5    26
```

I'm not saying that this function is a good way of doing what you are trying to do, but I think it accomplishes the job.  If it does, leave a comment, then maybe someone else can swing by and tell you how to do it more efficiently/safer.

The solution I provided is going to be prone to problems.  If your variable changes twice in the same loop, do you want to see that or not?  If you update one element of a matrix, do you want to see that or not?  Can your variables change dimensions or types in the loop?  If the variables don't change values in the loop, can you include those values anyways?

Perhaps this solution would work better for what you are trying to do:

```
function [xout yout] = foo
n=100;
x = 0;
y = 0;
xout = repmat(x,n,1);
yout = repmat(y,n,1);
for i = 1:n
  if x<i
      x=i^2;
      end
  if y^3<x
      y=sqrt(x);
  end
    xout(i)=x;
    yout(i)=y;
end
xout = unique(xout);
yout = unique(yout);

>> [x y] = foo

x =
     1
     4
    25
   676

y =
     1
     2
     5
    26
```

Comment: Ok, I understand both example, And thank you, this was what I was looking for (second code)

Comment: Best practice is to separate output variables with commas. [Fix]

Answer (score 2):

```
function [var1 var2] = my_func
    for n=1:5
        var1(n) = 2*n - 1;
        var2(:,:,n) = rand(3);  %create random 3x3 matrices 
    end
```

You can then call the function like this

```
>> [first second] = my_func

first =

     1     3     5     7     9


second(:,:,1) =

    0.3371    0.3112    0.6020
    0.1622    0.5285    0.2630
    0.7943    0.1656    0.6541


second(:,:,2) =

    0.6892    0.0838    0.1524
    0.7482    0.2290    0.8258
    0.4505    0.9133    0.5383


...
```

Comment: Ok, but how to keep track of all the values that has been added to the vector and matrix in the loop?,
So first = 1     3     5     7 ... 10 11...n
second   = 1     0     2     0     0
           0     0     4     0     0
           0     0     0     0     0
           0     0     0     0     0
           0     0     0     0     0

Comment: @darkcminor: I changed the example a little bit, but it is basically the same. Is that what you were looking for?